# How can I merge these functions?

Tags: functions

**Given Data**:
There are three functions

> f(x)=sin⁡(πx/2)
> g(x)=sin⁡(πx/3)
> h(x)=sin⁡(πx/4)

and a point *A(6,0)*.
**To find:**
Which of the given functions pass via point A.
**My Approach:**
As the  y coordinate of *pt.A* is 0, we know that any function which passes through *pt.A* will definitely pass via *x axis* at that point. Also, if a function passes through  *A(6,0)*, this implies that *for that function, at x=6 , the  y value, or f(6)  should equal 0.*
Plugging in *x =6*, we get:

> *f(6)=g(6)= 0 ;h(6)≠0*

⇒ The functions *f(x)  & g(x)*  pass via point A(6,0).
**My question:**
Is there any method by which I can merge/combine the equations of the given functions so that I get a single equation which serves the whole purpose (instead of plugging values in individual equations, can I merge all equations to get a single equation which works for all)? Is it possible?

Comment: You can make it a single multi-variable function $f(x,y)=\sin({\pi x\over y})$ but you still need to test three points $(6,2,0)$, $(6,3,0)$, $(6,4,0)$. If your question means "computationally perform a single test" then I think there is no such method.

Comment: okk...thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean.  If you're looking for a way to have three yes/no answers from the same process, that would be multivalued, and typically we define functions to only output a single value.

If you're fine with losing information in the process, there are some simple options that might give you a useful single value, depending on your application.  For example, if you are trying to test for at least one of these functions passing through (6,0), then you could use:

$$
q(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x) \cdot h(x) \\
$$

which would return 0 if and only if at least one of them were 0.

Or if you were only interested in the case where all the functions are 0, you could use:

$$
q(x) = (f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2 + (h(x))^2
$$

which (assuming your functions output real numbers and not imaginary numbers) will output zero if and only if all the functions are 0.

Comment: alright, got it...thanks

Comment: Well, think about it.  If f(6) is anything but zero, it'll become a positive number when squared, no matter how small.  Same for g(6) and h(6).  If you add positive numbers together, they only get farther from zero.  The only way for it to stay at zero is for all of them not to increase the total sum.

Comment: I should have qualified the above with: these are simple solutions.  It should be possible to craft a function that whose return value has a factor of +2 if f(x) is zero, a factor of +3 if g(x) is zero, and a factor of +5 if h(x) is zero, and zero otherwise.  That way, you could test for if any of them were zero, and be able to figure out which ones, based on factoring the answer.  Something like that.  But that seems more difficult.